# Some emails don't arrive

Tags: domain-name-system, email, cloudflare

Yesterday, somehow a DNS Zone File got removed from Cloudflare. So after re-editing the file everything seemed okay. Now there's the problem that some emails don't arrive in the inbox. Strange thing is that some email arrive (gmail for example) and others don't.

My MX records are the following:

```
somedomain.com        A        123.45.67.89     
somedomain.com        MX       0                mx1.somemailserver.com
somedomain.com        MX       10               mx2.somemailserver.com
```

TTL is set to automatic.

The mailserver itself is hosted somewhere else. There has never been a problem with mail, so its seems that the problem is due to the changed DNS Zone file. Does anyone know what possible problem there could be and what action can be taken?

Thanks in advance

Comment: MX records usually do not use priority `0`. There might be software which consider that value to be special. Does it help if you change the priority from `0` to `5`?

Comment: I will try that, thanks! Hopefully it will have some results.

Comment: Do A records for `mx1.somemailserver.com` and `mx2.somemailserver.com` exist and do they resolve to the correct ip addresses?